# How to determine if string ends with line break (EOL) in R?

Tags: string, r, newline

Is there any elegant way in R to determine of string ends with line break character ('\n' or '\r').

I was only able to come up with, which seems to work correctly, but I was wondering if there is a more elegant way.

```
d> s <- "string\n"
d> substr(s, nchar(s), nchar(s)) == '\n'
[1] TRUE
```

UPD:
There might be line breaks in the somewhere in a string. I need to know if it ends with line break.

```
s <- "string\nstring"
```

Comment: EOF normally means end of file, not line break (though I'm not familiar with R).

Comment: @KeithThompson thanks, it was a typo, fixed it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `grepl`:

```
grepl('(\r|\n)$', s)
```